# How can I flatten (combine?) a group of brush strokes in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, sketch-app, pathfinder, brush

***Warning:** I am not an expert with Adobe Illustrator*

I have done an illustration, using Adobe Illustrator, of some hair and a beard using only brushstrokes. I want to copy-and-paste this illustration into a Sketch file. However, there are so many brush strokes (paths?) that it takes some time to copy-and-paste the illustration between documents.

Does anybody know how I can *join/flatten/combine* (not sure of the right word because of my limited Illustrator knowledge) these brush strokes together so that it becomes more light-weight? At the moment, my computer has to do too many calculations.

[image]

Comment: Object -> Expand Apperance. Then pathfinder -> Unite.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. Why did you answer in the Comments section rather than the Answers section? In any case, thank you :-)

Comment: Its a duplicate answer... just cant be bothered to search for it. Also the answer is too short.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select all shapes that you need join, go to the main menu Object ->expand... the strokes lines must be converted into shapes, as in the example below

[image]

Next we will make all shapes unite, keep select all shapes you want together, go to the panel Pathfinder->Shapes Mode-> Unite and all shapes will became as one, if perhaps you don't watch the panel you can press Shift+Ctrl+F9 or go to main window and select Pathfinder.

[image]

Comment: Life saver dude! Thanks for this!